# What does the "--resource" mean by make controller command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I was using make controller command in Laravel. However, I did not understand the extension like --resource, --resource --model=Photo etc.

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

Comment: `php artisan help make:controller` ...

Comment: Follow the laravel documentation carefully. Hope you will get the answer to all your queries.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I already get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With --resource you will get controller with `index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy` methods and with --model you will bind that class into this methods